# Is dyeing home-grown roses fundamentally different from store-bought?

Tags: roses

I have a [Mme A. Meilland](https://www.rhs.org.uk/Plants/98512/Rosa-Peace-Madame-A-Meilland-(HT)/Details) rose in the garden, and I'd like to dye some of the blooms from it. There are plenty of guides online for buying roses from a shop and dyeing them all sorts of colours, but I'm also aware that shop roses might be treated with hormones and other chemicals to encourage them to bloom, and I'm not sure if this would make a difference.

Is it just as easy to dye roses from the garden? Given that I can take cuttings whenever I want, can I get a better result by cutting the stem before it's fully bloomed? Will I need to take better care of the cut stems given that the plants are untreated?